# How can I lock orientation for a specific view an Objective-C iPhone app in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I'm just trying to set up my app so that only one view can be viewed in landscape mode.

I've tried just about everything from `shouldAutorotate` to `supportedInterfaceOrientation` to `preferedInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`, and setting `[UIDevice currentDevice]`'s orientation to portrait. I have Landscape enabled in Info.plist and the project's general section.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly make your application portrait only in your info.plist

Create the following property in your AppDelegate class:

```
@property BOOL restrictRotation;
```

Then create the following method in your AppDelegate.m class:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(self.restrictRotation)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Create the following method in your ViewController and call it right before you want to permit landscape orientation. (Call it with true first in your viewDidLoad method to make sure rotation is restricted)

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

like this:

```
[self restrictRotation:NO];
```

and after you are done with your landscape view and its dismissed, call this immediately:

```
[self restrictRotation:YES];
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This works for me. =) I would also like to add checking "Requires Full Screen" in Deployment Info saved me a lot of time. Especially for iOS applications embedded in Master Detail View Controller or UINavigation Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

also change orientation after locking it:

```
-(void)forceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:orientation]forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

- set in app delegate

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 6 and above to clear the warning in AppDelegate while using [Gurtej Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31794608/3301811) answer you can replace the AppDelegate code with :

```
    - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window  API_AVAILABLE(ios(6.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos)
{
    if(self.restrictRotation)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate you could do this:

```
// Used to show a video in full screen
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int
{
    if let presentedViewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
    {
        if !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed() && presentedViewController is MyLandscapeModeViewController // insert your view controller class name here
        {
            // specify what kind of Orientation you want
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        }
    }
    // show every other View Controller in portrait
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```